# How to use Xcode in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, swift, react-native

I'm using react-native to build an app and Xcode is not supported on Ubuntu. So, I can't develop ios apps. Is there any way around so that I could run an ios simulator without having a Mac?
I found articles where they suggested to use a virtual box but I think it's not efficient to develop apps on a virtual box(just an intuition). Hackintosh is not an option for me. So, Is there any other way to run an ios simulator?

Comment: I believe for flawless experience you need a mac to test out your app, otherwise virtual box is the closest you can get

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is a proprietary software available only Apple based Macs.

If you want to you Xcode for developing iOS Apps, then you need a mac. Alternatively, you can also develop iOS apps using xamarin, phonegap and react using a ubuntu based machine.
You cannot for sure run Apple simulator on Ubuntu, you just can’t. If you want something outside Apple’s hardware you should try a Hackintosh, it's not big deal but in the end, for put your app on the Apple store you still need a regular Apple hardware.

Comment: Can we use xamarin in Ubuntu to run an ios simulator?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to install VMWare or any other VT then install OSX on a VM.

It works pretty good for testing.